# WordPress pagination with custom post type?

Tags: customization, custom-post-types, pagination

I have searched all over the web to find some solution, but none of them are working for me, can someone help me with this and explain what is wrong? I've spent 3 hours debugging and didn't find the issue.

Here is my code:

```
global $paged;
global $wp_query;
wp_reset_query();

$per_page = get_option('posts_per_page');
$cat_cars = get_term_by('slug', 'cars', 'category');
$page_links_total = ceil($cat_cars->count / $per_page);
$paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;

$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'cars',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'cat' => $cat_cars->term_id,
    'orderby' => 'date',
    'order' => 'DESC',
    'posts_per_page' => $per_page,
    'paged' => $paged
);

$page_links = paginate_links(array(
            'base' => add_query_arg('paged', '%#%'),
            'format' => '',
            'prev_text' => __('«'),
            'next_text' => __('»'),
            'end_size' => 2,
            'mid_size' => 1,
            'type' => 'plain',
            'total' => $page_links_total,
            'current' => $paged
        ));

$car_query = new WP_Query($args);
```

And later i call `have_posts`, `the_post`, etc..
This part works, until I go to the second page of my pagination and get nothing found.

Comment: I can't spot any immediate problems, debugging should narrow it down, so i'm inclined to ask, what did you do to debug?

Comment: print_r array,echo on every var,and wp_die('') - step by step. It is a problem with custom post types and pagination,but can't find the issue,and way to fix it

Comment: @user1147: Is there a reason you don't use `$car_query->max_num_pages` for the `total` argument of `paginate_links()`? This will probably not solve your problem, but it saves one expensive DB query.

Comment: @Jan Fabry : I know about man_num_pages,this is the way that I was creating pagination for wp.How you can see which query is expensive and which is not?

Comment: @user1147: Maybe it's not expensive, but I think you don't need it, since it seems you can get the variable you need from the main post query you have to do anyway.

Comment: yes,pretty permalinks,but should that be a problem ? pagination should work on no matter what permalink type is it,right ?

Comment: this is on template page - my custom page.Only query on my page.

Comment: @user1147: Maybe you should come to [the chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/6/stoppress) and we can debug it there.

Comment: @Jan Fabry,yes you are right,I don't need extra query.

Comment: It is on my localhost,can you give me some tips how to debugg it,maybe my approach was wrong doing debugging

Comment: This was discussed [in a chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/183/discussing-wpse-6343), the problem just disappeared.

Comment: It looks like that problem was with .htaccess file,when I update permalinks,it start working like should be working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar problem recently and determined the cause to be that when WordPress queries for posts in a category, it looks for posts with post_type equal to 'post' before it reaches the point where you query for post_type 'any' or some custom post type.  This doesn't cause a problem on page 1 because even if there are no posts it calls your template.  However on page 2 and so forth, it doesn't find any posts of post_type 'post' so it loads the 404 template before your template even gets a chance to modify the post_type parameter.

Is this a bug?  That's a good question.  I would say so because you should expect that if you register the 'category' taxonomy on other post_types, all post_types would show up in that archive, not just strictly posts.

Hopefully that helps.

Answer (score 0):

I have this code (cleaned) on a site, calling posts from a custom post type, and at the bottom the pagination, if there's more than 10 posts:

```
<?php $wp_query = new WP_Query();  $wp_query->query('post_type=mycpt&showposts=10'.'&paged='.$paged); 
while ($wp_query->have_posts()) : $wp_query->the_post();?>
<h3><?php the_title(); ?></h3>
<?php the_content();?>  
<?php endwhile; wp_reset_query(); ?>

<?php if (  $wp_query->max_num_pages > 1 ) { ?>
<div id="nav-below" class="navigation">
<div class="nav-previous"><?php next_posts_link( __( '<span class="meta-nav">&laquo;</span> Dicas antigas', 'twentyten' ) ); ?></div>
<div class="nav-next"><?php previous_posts_link( __( 'Dicas mais recentes <span class="meta-nav">&raquo;</span>', 'twentyten' ) ); ?></div>
</div>
<?php } ?>
```

Hope it can help.